# seting up PHP xdebug with PHP-debug ATOM package

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I am having trouble to get php-debug to work.
I am having this error:
[image]

Now to recreate my steps,

I installed Xdebug on my server by this [tutorial](https://medium.elegantly.rocks/enabling-php7-xdebug-for-vs-code-on-ubuntu-16-04-e13c5909119b)

I installed PHP-debug by tutorial provided [Here](https://github.com/gwomacks/php-debug) skipping this step:
[image]
as even tho there is screenshot nowhere it is written where I should put that configuration, (path, file.. nothing).

I am running ubuntu server with PHP 7.2, I am using a windows machine and editing from a remote server via remote FTP ATOM plugin.

Can anyone help solve this issue? Thanks

Error TXT:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
C:\Users\Stefan\.atom\packages\php-debug\lib\engines\dbgp\engine.js:58
Hide Stack Trace
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at PHPDebugEngine.hasContext (file:///C:/Users/Stefan/.atom/packages/php-debug/lib/engines/dbgp/engine.js:58:32)
    at PHPDebugEngine.tryGetContext (file:///C:/Users/Stefan/.atom/packages/php-debug/lib/engines/dbgp/engine.js:101:14)
    at HTMLElement.phpDebugRun (file:///C:/Users/Stefan/.atom/packages/php-debug/lib/php-debug.js:31:38)
    at CommandRegistry.handleCommandEvent (C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.33.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:349858)
    at CommandRegistry.dispatch (C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.33.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:11:348333)
    at AtomEnvironment.dispatchApplicationMenuCommand (C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.33.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:656662)
    at EventEmitter.t (C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.33.0\resources\app\static\<embedded>:1:664046)
    at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:217:7)
The error was thrown from the php-debug package. You can help by creating an issue. Please explain what actions triggered this error.
Create issue on the php-debug package
```

Comment: I added  the text form @PaulCrovella